# Which preposition goes better in the below statement?

Tags: prepositions

1: He is really good at/in/with the English language.

Which preposition goes better in the above statement?

2: He is really good at/in/with shooting.

Which preposition is the best match in the second statement?

Comment: Idiomatically, native speakers would normally say *"He's really good at Spanish"*, rather than *"at the Spanish language"*. Since that's the "idiomatic norm" for talking about language skills, if someone said *"He's really good **with** Spanish"*, many of us would cast about for a possible semantic distinction based on the less-than-likely preposition - perhaps concluding that he's good at interacting with Spanish *people*, for example. Using ***in*** is also uncommon outside a "school lessons" context (but there it would actually be the *more* common choice, meaning *in Spanish **classes***).

Comment: I would take "_He's really good with Spanish_" to imply some manner of ability associated _with_ the Spanish language - translating it, perhaps; it's more commonly used to refer to ability to _handle_ or _deal with_ something, e.g. "_He's really good with kids._" The expression I would take to mean an ability to interact with Spanish people would be "He's really good with _the_ Spanish." as we tend to say "_the_ Spanish" or "_the_ French" to refer to a people.

Comment: @Samuel: That *(good with Spanish = good **at translating** into or out of it)* is certainly another possible "creative interpretation". My point is simply that there's nothing *grammatically* wrong with using ***with*** instead of ***at*** - but since it's not the *standard* usage, we tend to look for an alternative meaning (basically, *anything* but the standard one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: What's wrong with 'the' English language? I remember the rule that we need to have an article before a specific noun, then why not 'the English language?'

Comment: @Frank: There's nothing at all wrong with 'the' English language. In fact, in most contexts where you're going to use the word "language" anyway, it's usually better to include the article. I'm just saying that idiomatically most native speakers would use plain *English*, rather than *the English language* in almost all contexts where your first example sentence might be used.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I understand that. I have also heard people using 'in' so frequently rather than 'with'. what if I say 'he is really good in shooting' or 'he is really good in reading'. Please suggest.

Comment: @Frank, without context, I can't imagine a native speaker using *in* in those examples; the appropriate connector would be *at* (and certainly not *with*, which as I explained in my previous comment is used very idiomatically.) You might say "He's really _good in situations_ that involve shooting or reading.", but I can think of few other phrases where "good in" would be natural to use.

Comment: @Frank: As I said, schoolchildren/students will have a tendency to say *good in [subject]*, because they're thinking in terms of ***in** the classroom/lesson period where/when [subject] is taught*. In other contexts, ***in*** would not be common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers/@Samuel Lijin: I think you have not left me with any doubt. Thanks for your support and giving this question a direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He is really good [at / in / with] English.

Which preposition you choose depends, like so many things in English, on the context and meaning you want to convey.

If you're talking about generic linguistic ability, use *at*. This case includes *the English language*, because that phrase refers to general English communication skills. When hearing *good at English*, people will understand that you mean *good at communicating in the English language*. *At* is more common than *in* or *with* when paired with a word like *English*, and it's the preposition you should choose if you really have no idea which one to use (and you have no good references to consult).

If you're talking about English as a class or school subject, use *in*. *Good in English* means *doing well in the formal study of the English language*. This applies when taking structured and evaluated lessons from a teacher; we wouldn't say *good in English* about someone who's teaching themselves as a hobby or in their spare time.

If you're talking about someone using English as a tool, use *with*. This one is quite rare and unlikely to see frequent (if any) use. To be *good with English* is to use it eloquently or deftly. For example, as a mode of translation, especially when performed by a non-native speaker or polyglot. It's possible that *with English* might refer to *interactions with people from England*, but in this case, the more correct construction is *with the English*.

Notice that in all of the examples, I've left off words like *language* and made *English* the sole target of the preposition. This highlights the way changing the preposition changes the meaning of the sentence, and shows how we often drop context specifying words which are (or we think should be) understood in English (i.e. in the English language). Whether you include them or not makes no difference to the choice of preposition, because you pick the preposition as if those words were in place, as they define the context. For example: *he's really good at [the] English [language]*.

> He is really good at shooting.

You've got it exactly right here. When we talk about generally performing some activity, we use *at*. For example, speaking, reading, and writing are the general activities in English, and we'd say someone is *good at them*.

Credits to [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26126/which-preposition-goes-better-in-the-above-statement#comment48613_26126) and [Samuel Lijin](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6597/samuel-lijin) for making some of these points in the question's comments.

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comment. Only someone with a master's degree in Nitpicking could fault the phrasing now. (And as one of the ["not-too-many-cooks"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/too-many-cooks-spoil-the-broth) involved in selecting & preparing the ingredients, I have no problem at all with the *semantic* content of this hearty broth! :)